# Get coordinations of a rectangle while animation is in action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I'm trying to get the coordinates of a rectangle while an animation is in action. You can see the code and type of animation here: http://jsfiddle.net/2UZM3/

As one can see, at the end of the animation the coordinates are printed. I want the coordinates to update permanently while the rectangle is moving.

Thank you for your help!

PS: The source code is originally from here: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-transition-easing-functions-with-kineticjs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a handler for `stage.onFrame` which outputs the item's coordinates. Simply start the `stage` when the user clicks the button to start the animation, and stop the `stage` when the callback on the `transitionTo` method is executed:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: "container",
        width: 500,
        height: 200
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    var greenBox = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 100,
        y: stage.getHeight() / 2,
        width: 100,
        height: 50,
        fill: 'green',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4
    });


    layer.add(greenBox);
    stage.add(layer);

    stage.onFrame(function(frame) {
        // Update print coordinates on each frame of animation loop
        jQuery("#coordinates").text(Math.round(greenBox.getX()) + "," + Math.round(greenBox.getY()));      
    });

    jQuery("#StartAnim").click(function() {

        // Start the timer running
        stage.start();

        greenBox.transitionTo({
            x: 300,
            duration: 1,
            easing: 'ease-in-out',
            callback: function() {
                // Stop the stage loop
                stage.stop();
            }
        });

    });
};
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/u3mE2/).

Comment: This is a great idea. It work's very well for the given problem. But I'm worrying about the efficiency. I also have discovered a possibility to write an own animation function (http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-animate-position-tutorial/). Would that be more effective or is the **profit only marginally**? If the latter is the case I would love to use your solution, because I can use the well implemented animation functions of KineticJS.

Comment: I think the performance difference at this stage will be minimal but my original solution does involve the addition of a further animation loop on top of the one I presume Kinetic is using to move the box with the transitionTo method and which you can access via the onFrame method of the stage. You would be far better hooking into that loop, the further positive outcome being that the resulting code is much cleaner. See my updated answer.

Comment: Awesome! I have not seen this possibility but it works really great. I am going to implement much more functionality while the animation is in action. Hence the code has to be efficient. Thank you very much for your help and your awesome solution!

Comment: No problem Amy, glad I was able to help.